# Will my client_id/client_secret for OAuth API work for other users?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform

Will my client_id/client_secret for Google OAuth 2.0 API work for other users (if I provide them with these values) of the same cloud project?

Or is it strictly necessary for each user to obtain his own client_id and client_secret? (But how to do this if the user is not technical enough? Is there a better way than to ask him or her to provide us his Google login/password?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i think there is a little misunderstanding here. 'client_id' and 'client_secret' identify your *application*, not any users. Maybe the word 'client' misled you: your app is the *client* of the service you use, in your case Google. But this has nothing to do with people using your app.

I suggest you to (re)read [this simplified doc](https://aaronparecki.com/2012/07/29/2/oauth2-simplified).